# Reading configuartion inside Automapper profile

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper in an asp.net core 2.0 project.  I register my mapping profiles using the automatic assembly scanning like so:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

I have mapping profile like below in my data layer:

```
public class JobDetailMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public JobDetailMappingProfile()
    {
        string dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; //todo: get this from main app config

        CreateMap<JobDetail, JobDetailViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.StartDate.ToString(dateFormat)))
            .ForMember(x => x.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.StartDate.ToString(dateFormat)));

        CreateMap<JobDetailViewModel, JobDetail>()
            .ForMember(x => x.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.StartDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )))
            .ForMember(x => x.EndDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.EndDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

    }
}
```

I want to read the dateFormat string from the projects settings file but I cannot figure out how to inject the configuration service or value into the profile and use assembly scanning at the same time.

Is the only way to do this to manually register each profile?

Comment: You can use your DI container instead.

Comment: How? I am registering my configuration as a service but how do I inject it into mapping profile?

Comment: As you always do, by creating your profile instances using your container.

Comment: Yes but this injects to controllers.  How do I make it inject to a mapping profile?

Comment: A profile is just another object.

Comment: If i add parameter signature to controller then service gets injected.  If I add it to profile it doesn't.  `services.AddAutoMapper();` does not inject services when it scans the assemblies.  This is why in my question I am asking if there is a way to inject service without having to manually register each profile (if I manually register profile I can inject whatever I like but then means I have to manually register each profile in startup instead of it automatically registering all my profiles).  I think maybe if you try it you will understand

Comment: Modern containers have conventions that allow you to register all types that derive from a base class for example. So you don't have to do it by hand.

Comment: How is this done in asp.net core 2.0?

Comment: I don't think what you are saying will work.  The `AddAutoMapper` method ignores parameters.

Comment: Of course it does. AM is not a DI container. If the default container in ASP.Net Core doesn't support this use case, you need a better container.

Comment: Anyway, if all else fails, you can rewrite your code using resolvers. Injection is supported in resolvers OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly scanning that the extension method `AddAutoMapper()` does with regards to adding profiles in it's implementation ultimately uses `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of the profile.  What you're looking for doesn't exist out-of-the-box.  But this is an extension method that you can write yourself:

```
public static class AutoMapperExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection @this, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var assembliesToScan = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var allTypes = assembliesToScan.Where(a => a.GetName().Name != "AutoMapper").SelectMany(a => a.DefinedTypes).ToArray();
        var profiles = allTypes.Where(t =>
        {
            if (typeof(Profile).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t))
                return !t.IsAbstract;
            return false;
        }).ToArray();

        Mapper.Initialize(expression =>
        {
            foreach (var type in profiles.Select(t => t.AsType()))
                expression.AddProfile((Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(type, configuration));
        });

        return @this;
    }
}
```